# How can i create add dynamically imageview below the previous one?

Tags: java, imageview, dynamically-generated

this is my .xlm file. Sorry but i'm new in java and android. I want to add  new imageview, dynamically, on layout, and everyone will be below the previous one:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/frame1">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
`
```

and this is my for cycle:

```
`

for (int i = 0;i < num_max; i++){
                name = String.valueOf(i) + ".jpg";
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START);
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                LinearLayout frameLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame1);
                mImageView = new ImageView (this);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url_image+name);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                frameLayout.addView(mImageView,rlp);}
```

`

but doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: please describe, what exactly doesn't work. Do you get any errors, if so please add the stacktrace.

Comment: no. There aren't errors. I want to add dynamically, imageview below the previous one with vertical scrollview, but with this code, i can't to do this and i haven't other ideas to do this

Answer (score 0):

Spezifiy below which view element your image view should be placed with:

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.theviewwhichisabove);
```

and then call `mImageView.setLayoutParams(rlp);`